# Magento 2 api : order status

Tags: magento2, api, sales-order

I am looking for a way to update order status with rest api (php) based on order ID.

I tried several things from the doc (well at least, I have found below code Without success)

```
    $data = array(
        "entity" => array(
            'entity_id'=>'000000159',
            'status'=>'pending2'
        )
    );

$retour = $this->api->put("orders",$data );
```

How can I accomplish this.

Comment: 'entity_id'=>'000000159' it's not entity_id but real_order_id

Answer (score 0):

```
$entity_id = 955;
$request_url='http://example.com/rest/V1/orders';
$data_json = [
    "entity"=> [
        "entity_id" => $entity_id,
        "state" => "processing",
        "status" => "Processing"
    ]
];
$data_string = json_encode($data_json);
$ch = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.json_decode($token),
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response =  json_decode($response);
print_r($response);
curl_close($ch);
```